# MongoDB update ObjectId field

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a document that has an attribute which is an ObjectId. For example anchor field in the code below:

```
{ "__v" : 0, "_id" : ObjectId("5654d896481c5186ddaf4481"), "anchor" : ObjectId("565480e5481c5186ddaf446c"), "base_url" : "http://example.com"}
```

I saw the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) but it is not clear how to update an ObjectId reference field. I want this reference to just point to another `anchor` document, can I just place the ObjectId as a string like this:

```
db.categories.update(
   { },
   {
      $set {anchor: "5654d47a481c5186ddaf4479"}
   },
   { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but I think you want your update to be like: `{ $set: { anchor: ... } }`. Otherwise it will remove your `base_url` property.

Comment: How your updated document will look like?

Comment: Is the new `_id` from another collection or the same collection? I see you already accepted an answer but perhaps there is a better way as the one shown.

Comment: It is from another collection, does it matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ObjectId()`:

```
db.categories.update(
   { },
   {
      $set: { anchor: ObjectId("5654d47a481c5186ddaf4479") }
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#core-object-id-class

> The mongo shell provides the ObjectId() wrapper class to generate a new ObjectId,...

Comment: Hmm, and what if I want to build the ObjectId from other parts? I'm trying `.updateMany({ "_id": ObjectId('613bfe197524c621b9953012') }, [ { "$set": { "carnival": ObjectId({ "$substrBytes": [ "$_partition", 25, 24 ] }) } } ], {})' and getting "Argument passed in does not match the accepted types"…

Comment: @IanBailey-Mortimer docs say it takes a 12 digit hexadecimal string. i’m not sure you can execute any operations inside ObjectID(), but if you can it’ll have to result in a 12 digit hexadecimal string. looks like you are trying to do 24 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it by first extracting the bit of the string I needed into a separate new field, then filtering by those values to set the new ObjectId field.